# Google visualisation charts - colors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on project were I have to put different colors on the graph, between some zone's. I want color in blue , red , yellow, green

This is my result
[image]

I want something like this

[image]
This is my code

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Week', 'Zone 0 - 60%', 'Zone 60 - 70%', 'Zone 70 - 80%', 'Zone 80 - 90%', 'Zone 90% +'],
        ['W45', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18],
        ['W46', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
        ['W47', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
        ['W48', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
        ['W49', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
        ['W50', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
        ['W60', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
        ['W61', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
        ['W62', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
        ['W63', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
        ['W64', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
        ['W65', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
        ['W66', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
        ['W67', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
        ['W68', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
        ['W69', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
        ['W70', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
        ['W71', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
        ['W72', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
        ['W73', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12]
    ]);

    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        chartArea: {
            width: '90%',
            height: '80%',
        },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Answer (score 1):

use a *classic* chart, instead of a *material* chart

*classic* --> `packages: ['corechart']` + `google.visualization.ColumnChart`

*material* --> `packages: ['bar']` + `google.charts.Bar`

*material* charts are limited when it comes to available options for styling
see for options not available for *material* --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

there is an option to style a *classic* chart similar to *material*

```
theme: 'material'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStuff,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStuff() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Week', 'Zone 0 - 60%', 'Zone 60 - 70%', 'Zone 70 - 80%', 'Zone 80 - 90%', 'Zone 90% +'],
      ['W45', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18],
      ['W46', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
      ['W47', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
      ['W48', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
      ['W49', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
      ['W50', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
      ['W60', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
      ['W61', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
      ['W62', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
      ['W63', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
      ['W64', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
      ['W65', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
      ['W66', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
      ['W67', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
      ['W68', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
      ['W69', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12],
      ['W70', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16],
      ['W71', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12],
      ['W72', 26, 25, 23, 10, 16],
      ['W73', 28, 19, 29, 40, 12]
  ]);

  var options = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      chartArea: {
          width: '90%',
          height: '80%',
          top: 48
      },
      bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
      isStacked: true,
      theme: 'material',
      legend: {
          maxLines: 2,
          position: 'top'
      }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```